# How do I pipe in command run using backtick?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a bash command,

```
a=`xyz | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

which was used to get version number

I was using it a number of times, to avoid redundancy, I decided to store it as a string and execute it whenever I need, but now only the stdout of xyz is getting stored to the variable.

This is how I'm doing it,

```
cmd="xyz | head -n 1 | awk '{print \$2}'"
a=`$cmd`
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it? Also suggest if there is a simpler/better way of achieving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> suggest if there is a simpler/better way of achieving it.

You command can be shortened to:

```
xyz | awk '{print $2; exit}'
```

And you can create a function for this rather than storing in a string:

```
mycmd() {
    xyz | awk '{print $2; exit}'
}
```

And use it as:

```
a=$(mycmd)
```

Comment: What OP is doing wrong is quoting a command (pipeline) containing shell metacharacters, they loose their effect (everything ends up as an argument to `xyz`). Using `eval` can fix this, but a function is so much neater.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only want the second field of the first line of the output of the command `xyz`, and store it in variable `a`. Then why not use Bash directly to do just that?

```
read _ a _ < <(xyz)
```